# How can I make this recursive function not go all the way to out of bounds in the array?

Tags: java

```
 static int[] CharSearch(char[][] array1, char a, int r, int c, int[] array2) {
    boolean cont = true;
    int count = 0;
    while (cont == true) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
                while (array1[i][j] == a) {
                    count++;

                    int up = up(array1, a, r, c, cont, count);
                    int down = down(array1, a, r, c, cont, count);
                    int left = left(array1, a, r, c, cont, count);
                    int right = right(array1, a, r, c, cont, count);
                    array2[i + j] = count + up + down + left + right;
                    return CharSearch(array1, a, r, c, array2);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return array2;
}

static int up(char[][] array1, char a, int r, int c, boolean cont, int count) {
    if (array1[r - 1][c] == a) {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}

static int down(char[][] array1, char a, int r, int c, boolean cont, int count) {
    if (array1[r + 1][c] == a) {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}

static int left(char[][] array1, char a, int r, int c, boolean cont, int count) {
    if (array1[r][c - 1] == a) {
        count++;
    }
    return count;

}

static int right(char[][] array1, char a, int r, int c, boolean cont, int count) {
    if (array1[r][c + 1] == a) {
        count++;
    }
    return count;

}
}
```

How can i make this recursive function not go out of bounds? I can't think of a way right now, and I changed up my original method to this. Thanks.

This is the edited version with some new if statement methods to make it easier to clean up to see what is actually wrong. Still getting the error of index out of bounds.

Comment: Please fix your indentation

Comment: What is it meant to do? A two-dimensional array slice can be specified with 5 parameters, such as array reference, starting row, starting column, ending row, ending column.

Comment: It's supposed to search within a 2D array of characters (A,B,Cs) and find groupings and record how many groups there are and the largest member within the group (in terms of letters per group)

Comment: your method is doing to many things. Split it into separate methods with single responsibilities. Keep it modular. Also maybe use an ArrayList from time to time..

Comment: do you have an example call?  i see a hard coded 19 in there which im unsure how to handle.

Comment: oops that was just trying something out.

Comment: Hey guys, so there is a new method up there i did with the suggestion of donfuxx, cleaned it up a bit while adding new methods